# Convert openssl AES in Php to Python AES

Tags: php, python, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a php file which is as follow:

```
$encryption_encoded_key = 'c7e1wJFz+PBwQix80D1MbIwwOmOceZOzFGoidzDkF5g=';

function my_encrypt($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cfb'));

    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cfb', $encryption_key, 1, $iv);

    // The $iv is just as important as the key for decrypting, so save it with encrypted data using a unique separator (::)
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}

function my_decrypt($data, $key) {
    // Remove the base64 encoding from key
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);

    // To decrypt, split the encrypted data from IV - unique separator used was "::"
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2);

    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cfb', $encryption_key, 1, $iv);
}

$data = 'USER_ID||NAME||EMAIL||MOBILE';
$data_encrypted = my_encrypt($data, $encryption_encoded_key);
echo $data_encrypted;
$data_decrypted = my_decrypt($data_encrypted, $encryption_encoded_key);
echo "Decrypted string: ". $data_decrypted;
```

This works fine, and is able to encrypt/decrypt with the encryption key, now i also have a python file:

```
import hashlib
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

encryption_encoded_key = 'c7e1wJFz+PBwQix80D1MbIwwOmOceZOzFGoidzDkF5g='

def my_encrypt(data, key):
    #Remove the base64 encoding from key
    encryption_key = base64.b64decode(key)
    #Generate an initialization vector
    bs = AES.block_size
    iv = Random.new().read(bs)

    cipher = AES.new(encryption_key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    #Encrypt the data using AES 256 encryption in CBC mode using our encryption key and initialization vector.
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(data)

    #The iv is just as important as the key for decrypting, so save it with encrypted data using a unique separator (::)
    return base64.b64encode(encrypted + '::' + iv)


def my_decrypt(data, key):
    #Remove the base64 encoding from key
    encryption_key = base64.b64decode(key)

    #To decrypt, split the encrypted data from IV - unique separator used was "::"
    encrypted_data, iv = base64.b64decode(data).split('::')

    cipher = AES.new(encryption_key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)

    return cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data)

data = 'USER_ID||NAME||EMAIL||MOBILE'

print "Actual string: %s" %(data)
data_encrypted = my_encrypt(data, encryption_encoded_key)
print data_encrypted

data_decrypted = my_decrypt(data_encrypted, encryption_encoded_key)
print "Decrypted string: %s" %(data_decrypted)
```

This also works fine when i try to use this from python, it is able to encrypt/decrypt input string, 
I want to encrypt using php file and decrypt the output in python, both should use AES 256 Encryption using CFB mode, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: where is the process breaking down? can you print out your parsed key, iv, data, etc prior to running the encrypt/decrypt operation for each method?  that will at least give you a starting point

Comment: Oh and one thing to watch out for - not knowing much about python or php, be on the lookout for reference types.  the `iv` is potentially modified through each block when running through the encrypt/decrypt operations.  If you were to (as a simple example) start with an iv of `...0001`, after the first block, that iv might be represented as `...0002`.  Make sure you're appending the "original" iv in both implementations, rather than the (potentially) modified iv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use [CFB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_.28CFB.29) you need to specify a *segment size* for it. OpenSSL has `aes-256-cfb` (which is 128 bit), `aes-256-cfb1` (i.e. 1-bit) and `aes-256-cfb8` (8 bit) (and similar modes for AES-128 and 192). So you are using 128 bit cfb in your php code.

The Python library accepts a `segment_size` argument to `AES.new`, but the default is *8*, so you are using different modes in the two versions.

To get the Python code to decrypt the output of the PHP code, add a segment size of 128 to the cipher object:

```python
cipher = AES.new(encryption_key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
```

(N.B. this is using the newer [PyCryptodome fork](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome) of PyCrypto. PyCrypto has a bug here and won’t work.)

Alternatively, you can get the PHP code to use CFB-8 by setting the cipher (don’t change both, obviously):

```php
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cfb8', $encryption_key, 1, $iv);
```

Comment: Works perfectly now, is there any better way to approach this ? like is there any openssl wrapper in python where i can do the same instead of trying to guess encryption type, lets say the php code changes cipher from aes to cast5-cbc, so that i wont have rewrite my encryption/decryption methods ?

Comment: nice answer, I have a feeling this issue have something to do with segment_size but no idea how to change...